# Pagination Conundrum

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I used Codeigniter to build my site, and everything is going peachy, except when it comes to dealing with pagination. Because database queries are driven by data passed from my URL, this is screwing everything up. I'm SURE I'm overlooking something obvious, but this is my issue:

```
/events/town/venue/event-name
```

All fine and works as expected; the method takes the parameters from the URL to get the data and deliver it. But my question is - what do I do when I want to paginate my Events page? I.e.

```
/events/2
/events/3
...etc
```

As far as my controller, and my routes are concerned, the page number here is considered a **town**, which it isn't. How do I get around this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> "Test" your **town** or "page number" uri segment, if it is integer then
>   you sure know that you are looking for pagination thing, otherwise
>   "normal" behavior of your controller/method pattern.

using PHPs [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/is_numeric).

A little pseudo code:

```
if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(n))) {
    //pagination stuff
} else {
    //regular behavior
}
```

*In case you are using `aplication/config/routes.php` consider using `_remap()` instead (for this certain controller).*

or use routes as following:

```
$route['events/(:num)'] = "events/page/$1"; //pagination "behind the scene" with method "page" (that is not seen by user).
$route['events/town/venue/(:any)'] = "events/town/venue/$1";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but testing for numeric doesn't seem like a solid solution to me. In this instance it works, but there are various places across my site which will face the same issues, and sometimes the parameters may be numeric. But the routes bit has given me something to think about...

Comment: I would go with routes.php myself, its much cleaner, good luck.